# TS files in published libraries are often a sign of a badly packaged library

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, jasmine

I am trying to do unit test in Ionic 4 ,so we have made mobilecore library and put in node_modules and from there we are using components, services and decorators (all files are in ts format they are not tsc compiled).

I have created a blank project and in homepage I am calling @PageTrack decorator for tracking page in firebase , I have included in include in tsconfig.spec.json and tsconfig.app.json but still I am getting error:

> ERROR in
>   ./node_modules/mobile-core/src/app/decorators/page-track.decorator.ts
>   Module build failed (from
>   ./node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/index.js): Error:
>   D:\Testing\testingdemo\node_modules\mobile-core\src\app\decorators\page-track.decorator.ts
>   is missing from the TypeScript compilation. Please make sure it is in
>   your tsconfig via the 'files' or 'include' property. The missing file
>   seems to be part of a third party library. TS files in published
>   libraries are often a sign of a badly packaged library. Please open an
>   issue in the library repository to alert its author and ask them to
>   package the library using the Angular Package Format
>       at AngularCompilerPlugin.getCompiledFile (D:\Testing\testingdemo\node_modules@ngtools\webpack\src\angular_compiler_plugin.js:869:23)
>       at plugin.done.then (D:\Testing\testingdemo\node_modules@ngtools\webpack\src\loader.js:41:31)
>       at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)  @ ./src/app/home/home.page.ts 3:0-80 8:4-13  @
>   ./src/app/home/home.page.spec.ts  @ ./src sync .spec.ts$  @
>   ./src/test.ts

Can someone suggest me where I am wrong or how to exclude this decorator while using `npm run test`

Comment: Did you consider to run `tsc` on your "library". As that's what the thing is complaining about, furthermore why wouldn't you run `tsc` any how?

Comment: If I run tsc on my code, it is possible to import all components ,services , module in my project directly.

Comment: Yes that's possible, as they are exported.

Comment: I got my solution thanks @r3dst0rm